# LINQ to SQL performing OR on strings

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm just looking to perform a LINQ query to return a group of course ID's and Course Titles which are running next year. As part of this I need to perform an OR query as I'm also looking to return data relating to next year as well which is held as a string in my databse and is the only issue I'm having, so any help would be appreciated.

```
var result = (
    from a in Offering
    join b in Courseinfo on a.CourseID equals b.CourseID
    into temp
    from c in temp
    where c.Year == "10/11" || "11/12"
    select new { c.CourseID, c.CourseTitle }).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

Comment: "10/11" looks more like a date than a year to me. :)

Comment: It looks like "year" isn't actually a year - I'm guessing that's a "school year" because it spans two calendar years.

Comment: Yes it refers to an academic year, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite your query as `where c.Year == "10/11" || c.Year == "11/12"`.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this but it was saying Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and type 'string'. However it now works so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to dynamically select years then you could do something like this

```
var years = new List<string>{"1989", "1994", "2004", "2007"};
```

and then change the `where` to

```
where years.Contains(c.Year)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic syntax error - in C# you can't say:

> "Where the year is 2010 or 2011".

You have to say:

> "Where the year is 2010, or the year is 2011"

So you rewrite this:

```
where c.Year == "10/11" || "11/12"
```

as this:

```
where c.Year == "10/11" || c.Year == "11/12"
```